# Spring Cloud Bus does not longer support POST requests to /actuator/bus-refresh

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

I've found out that Spring Cloud Bus does not support POST requests to **/actuator/bus-refresh** on `Spring Cloud` version `2020.0.0`. When I try to send it, I recieve 405 "Method Not Allowed". Is there any way to automatically refresh all my client services' configurations without using **/monitor** and git webhooks or downgrading Spring Cloud version?

I have included `spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp` and `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependencies, `bus-refresh` endpoint is exposed. RabbitMQ is up and running, springCloudBus topic is created and queues are added when my services start. It fetches property sources to my Config Server when I do GET request to **/actuator/bus-refresh**, but my client services properties files are not refreshed and messages are not added to queues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latest breaking changes logs found [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes)
the bus-refresh endpoint is renamed to busrefresh.

> bus-env is now busenv

> bus-refresh is now busrefresh

Comment: Great. That solved the issue. Attached is the CURL I executed 
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8090/actuator/busrefresh'